# Did K'Ehleyr know about B'Elanna Torres, or vice versa?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

K'Ehleyr was a Klingon/Human hybrid and the mate of Worf. She held a high position within the Federation, yet often lamented her dual nature. B'Elanna Torres was also a hybrid of the two races, albeit with the parentage switched around.

K'Ehleyr noted that although the DNA was compatible, it required medical "help" to occur - therefore making hybrids of the two races rare. Although I'm sure the two never met, largely due to the former's fate, **did either of the women know about the other one?**

Acceptable answer can come from beta canon - novels & games. If the answer is "No", that's also a perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3):

## I cannot find any evidence that they knew about each other.

- They never appeared or were mentioned in the same episode.
- There is no mention of of K'Ehleyr on B'Elanna's [memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B%27Elanna_Torres) (canon) or [memory beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/B%27Elanna_Torres) (non-canon) articles.
- There is only one mention of B'Elanna on K'Ehleyr's [memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/K%27Ehleyr) article, and nothing on [memory beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/K%27Ehleyr).

The only connection between the two (from the MA page) seems to be that the actress who played K'Ehleyr also played the Female Q, who did indeed meet B'Elanna.